# Coverage tab in dev tools in chrome, it doesn't highlight loaded css with green and unused csss with red

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Coverage tab in the Chrome dev tools doesn't highlight loaded CSS with green and unused CSS with red.

[image: screenshot showing the coverage tab]

I'm using chrome Version `77.0.3865.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)`,
OS is Ubuntu `18.04`

Comment: Maybe it doesn't work with minimized files.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that everything on the testing webpage is loaded and functioning properly, it is important to give the page enough time to fully load. Wait a few minutes and then scroll from top to bottom to check for any sliders or animations, make sure all are loaded and working.

During the loading process, you will notice the percentage value in the coverage area changing from its initial value.

Once the page is fully loaded, return to the coverage area and click on stop. Check the CSS and JS files for results, which will be highlighted for your convenience.